# Unable to open Excel from Explorer when userform is opened

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Hi I am working on a project where I have to let users open excel while the Userform is opened.I can navigate through other excel files but not the one from Explorer.Please help.It would be of great help for me.

```
    Option Explicit 
    Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.OnlyOneOfMe" 
    Dim wks As Worksheet 
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
    wks.Protect Password:="Nothing", _ 
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True 
Next wks 
    End Sub 
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
 'important to reset this
Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False 
    End Sub 

 Private Sub OnlyOneOfMe() 
Dim XlApp As Excel.Application 
On Error Goto BAD 
With Application 
    If Me.ReadOnly Or .Workbooks.Count > 1 Then 
        Me.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly 
        Set XlApp = New Excel.Application 
        XlApp.Visible = True 
        XlApp.Workbooks.Open (Me.FullName) 
        Goto BAD 
    Else 
         'stop opening from explorer (but not from excel)
        .Visible = False 
        .IgnoreRemoteRequests = True 
        UserForm1.Show 
        .Visible = True 
        .Quit 
    End If 
    Exit Sub 
End With 
BAD:     If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR" 
Set XlApp = Nothing 
Me.Close False 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you describe a little more about what you're trying to do? And what you're trying to allow? (This will be too much for a *comment*, please update/revise your original Q)  What I see is that you're changing `Me.ChangeFileAccess` to read only, then opening the workbook in a new instance of Excel.  Is the problem that this new instance is then unresponsive?  Why are you opening the same file in two instances of Excel?

Comment: Hi David I am new to VB coding. My question is that I have this excel file wherein a Userform opend up on workbook_open event . I was unable to view any Excel sheets earlier since the userform used to cover the entire excel. After adding the above Code I am able to view all the excel Except for the one from Explorer that is of Xls format. Kindly help me on this. Please update the above code if it is wrong.

Comment: Does the user need the ability to manipulate the workbooks which are already open?

Answer (score 0):

If the UserForm is modal it will lock the instance of excel until the form is closed.
You need to make the UserForm non Modal or close it after the workbook is opened.

Or you may Disable events before opening the workbook, that will prevent the UserForm to popup.

Just put this before the line where you open the workbook
`Application.EnableEvents = False`

And after the opening line enable the evens again
    `Application.EnableEvents = True`

And you need to Enable/Disable the events for correct instance/application since you are opening new.
like this:

   `XlApp.EnableEvents = False
   XlApp.Workbooks.Open (Me.FullName) 
   XlApp.EnableEvents = True`

But you probably wont need to open new excel instance if this would work.

Also put the events enabling line to the ErrorHandling
`If Err Then Application.EnableEvents = True: MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR"`

Comment: @David, No the user dont have to manipulate the excel sheets they just have to view them.

Comment: @RadekThanks for the Code Provided above but still I am unable to see the Excel opened from Explorer otherwise all other excels are visible to me. The Userform covers the entire sheet

Comment: The intention of the code was that the UserForm wont appear at all. Ah and I had mistake in the code, which I fixed now. The first line should be XlApp.EnableEvents = False (was True before).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to hide all opened UserForms.
Put this right after you open the workbook:

`For Each Object In VBA.UserForms
    Object.Hide
Next`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a visual basic script to open up the userform in your VBA project. Put the following code on a plain text file and save it with the '.vbs' extension.(This must be in the same folder as the excel file containing the userform)

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, curDir
Dim xlObj, file
Dim fullPath

Const xlMaximized = -4137 'constant to maximizes the background excel window

On Error Resume next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
file ="\~$YourExcelFileName.xlsm"             
fullPath = curdir & File

If fso.FileExists(fullPath) Then ' checks if the project is open or not

    MsgBox "The project is in use!",64, "Notificación"

Else

    file ="\YourExcelFileName.xlsm"           
    fullPath = curdir & file

    Set fso = Nothing       
    Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlObj

        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        .Visible = False
        .Workbooks.Open fullPath
        .IgnoreRemoteRequests = True
        .Run "mainMethod"   

    End With

    set xlObj=Nothing       

End If
```

... then add a public subroutine in your vba project to listen the call from the previous VBScript (name the subroutine as above, I've called mainMethod)

```
Public Sub mainMethod()

   UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

... you also have to attach an userform_terminate event to indicate that when you close the userform it must quit the current and active instance of excel:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

   Application.Quit

End Sub
```

... and of course you have to write a workbook's before_close event to reset the .IgnoreRemoteRequests to false, as follow (You can also write this in the previous userform_terminate event handler, but I believe this a tidier way to do it):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

  ThisWorkbook.Saved = True 'if needed
  Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False

End Sub
```

Once you manage to do that, you'll have a very clean stand alone application, no one will notice it comes from an excel file and it won't interfeers with any other excel instance. Good Luck.

***Andrés Alejandro García Hurtado***

Comment: I am unable to get the above code to run since it was throwing some unusual error as to harm the computer and the work environment.

Comment: Hmmm.. What is the error you're getting? Can you give me further description of it, so I could tell you how to handle it.

Comment: @AndresSorry for the delay in response it gives me some security issue error.

Comment: @Radek I dont understand wants going wrong, but now as well the excel are not opening up. Can you help me with the code??

Comment: You need to be sure to make the Evens enabled after the workbook is opened and also if any error appears. Put the .EnableEvents = True line in the error handling so even if the error appears, the events are enabled. This mehod disable the events for whole excel instance, so even when the macro finishs or the workbook is closed, the events are still disabled if you havent enabled them.

Comment: Can you please update the above code since I am still having the issue of not opening the excel from explorer. which are in .xls format. help please...

Comment: Hi All Is there a way that I can let the user to play around with the current sheet which contains the userform and also view other excel sheets??Please reply?

Comment: Hmmm so my solution didn't work for you. To make excel work again you have to follow these instructions: Go to the excel menu - click on Excel options - click on the advanced tab - Scroll down to "General" - uncheck "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)"  once you do all of the steps you won't longer see that problem

Comment: Thanks to all for you help.. It started working fine. The only issue I have currently is whenever an excel is open and I try opening this macro enabled workbook it asks me do you want to save before switching the status?? Can you rectify what is causing the error from the above code I think I am changing the status to read only might be the error can anyone please edit the code for me...